# WordPress Slider Plugin for Bootstrap

Tags: wordpress

I really need help. I'm a total beginner on Bootstrap but I was a handed a WordPress site with all pages having different sets of sliders, and some of the images need to  have links. Is there a secure and free WP plugin for that? Thank you very much! I really appreciate it!!

Answer (score 0):

Please check below plugin link for multiple responsive slier

https://wordpress.org/plugins/responsive-slideshow/

in the plugin have option to create multiple slider with different short code.